# Passed List is empty using ASP.Net MVC 3/jQuery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following ViewModel:

```
public class CheckListInfo
{
    public int CheckListQuestionID { get; set; }
    public string QuestionText { get; set; }
    public bool Value { get; set; }
}

public class AddEditWorkOrderViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Work Order ID")]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Work Order Number")]
    public string WorkOrderNumber { get; set; }

    public List<CheckListInfo> CheckListInfos = new List<CheckListInfo>();
}
```

and the following controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Update(int ID, AddEditWorkOrderViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        BusinessLogic.WorkOrders blWorkOrders = new BusinessLogic.WorkOrders();
        WorkOrder workOrder = blWorkOrders.GetWorkOrder(ID);

        Mapper.CreateMap<AddEditWorkOrderViewModel, DataModels.WorkOrder>();
        Mapper.Map(model, workOrder);

        blWorkOrders.UpdateWorkOrder(workOrder);

        return Json(new { success = true });
    }

    return Json(new { success = false });
}
```

and the following jQuery:

```
var checkListQuestionInfos = new Array();
var checkListQuestion = { CheckListQuestionID: 1, QuestionText: 'Test1', Value: true };
checkListQuestionInfos.push(checkListQuestion);

var data = {
    WorkOrderNumber: $("#WorkOrderNumber").val(),
    CheckListInfos: checkListQuestionInfos
}

$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Update", new { id = @Model.ID })',
    type: 'POST',
    async: false,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
    data: JSON.stringify(data)
});
```

The ID and WorkOrderNumber is coming through just fine in my model, but the List is empty.  What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out.  The line:

```
public List<CheckListInfo> CheckListInfos = new List<CheckListInfo>();
```

should have been

```
public List<CheckListInfo> CheckListInfos { get; set; }
```

Changing this fixed it.