# MVC 3 sending class JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

My parameter **KontrolkaSamTekstLista** get null data to controller **ActionResult KontrolkaSubmit()** but all send action to ajax looks okay.

Class

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Modul_Stypendia.Kontrolki
{
    public class KontrolkaSamTekst
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Kolejnosc { get; set; }
        public string Tekst { get; set; }
        public int Wypelnia { get; set; }
        public List<string> Przyklad { get; set; }

    }
}
```

here list is empty **IMPORTANT**

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult KontrolkaSubmit(List<KontrolkaSamTekst> KontrolkaSamTekstLista)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);  


            return Json(new { msg = "Successfully added " + KontrolkaSamTekstLista[0].Tekst });
        }
```

Ajax

```
$("#waznyTest").click(function () {

        var KontrolkaSamTekst = {
            Id: idDane,
            Kolejnosc: kolejnoscDane,
            Tekst: tekstDane,
            Wypelnia: wypelniaDane,
            Przyklad: przykladDane
        }

        KontrolkaSamTekstLista = [];
        KontrolkaSamTekstLista.push(KontrolkaSamTekst);
        KontrolkaSamTekstLista.push(KontrolkaSamTekst);
        KontrolkaSamTekstLista.push(KontrolkaSamTekst);

        $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("KontrolkaSubmit", "styStypendia")',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            KontrolkaSamTekstLista: KontrolkaSamTekstLista
        },
        type: 'post',
        traditional: true,
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#target').html(data.msg);
        }
    });

    });
```

sent data looks okay

[image]

sent data

[image]

CORRECT ANSWER

```
 $.ajax({
            url: '/styStypendia/KontrolkaSubmit',
            type: 'POST',
            async: false,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
            data: JSON.stringify(KontrolkaSamTekstLista)
        });
```

the best example [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12029661/passed-list-is-empty-using-asp-net-mvc-3-jquery-ajax)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to stringify your data, and not pass in an object, but the array directly:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("KontrolkaSubmit", "styStypendia")',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
        data: JSON.stringify(KontrolkaSamTekstLista),
        type: 'post',
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#target').html(data.msg);
        }
```

Comment: I check this but doesn`t help

Comment: Could you show me what is sent over the wire? Also if you're using IE7 then you need a library to use JSON.stringify. Otherwise this should work

Comment: I would like to see what is exactly sent to the server (ie: the raw request with the JSON in it). You can check this with a tool like httpfiddler, te chrome developer tools or firebug.

Comment: I added this information as a picture before but now I show more information "last picture - sent data" look into my post

Comment: Looking at your picture I noticed that you till have `data: JSON.stringify({ ,` Please take a close look at my answer again and try it (the data part). Copy it exactly and try it again please.

Comment: I test this before data: JSON.stringify(KontrolkaSamTekstLista) but doesn`t help. Now I try again but also doesn`t help.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30209/discussion-between-kenneth-and-rafael-junior-mvc-developer)

Comment: Hi, I fixed this problem (look into my post). Now I can send a lot of class via JSON. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Ah, yes, indeed, the contenttype was needed! I edeited my answer just for future reference.

Comment: really thanks for you time you spend a lot of time with this.

Answer (score 2):

Your AJAX method should look like this

```
$("#waznyTest").click(function () {

    var KontrolkaSamTekst = {
        Id: idDane,
        Kolejnosc: kolejnoscDane,
        Tekst: tekstDane,
        Wypelnia: wypelniaDane,
        Przyklad: przykladDane
    }

    KontrolkaSamTekstListaC = [];
    KontrolkaSamTekstListaC.push(KontrolkaSamTekst);
    KontrolkaSamTekstListaC.push(KontrolkaSamTekst);
    KontrolkaSamTekstListaC.push(KontrolkaSamTekst);

    $.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("KontrolkaSubmit", "styStypendia")',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(KontrolkaSamTekstLista), // CHANGED
    type: 'post',
    traditional: true,
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
        $('#target').html(data.msg);
    }
});

});
```

Comment: OOPS, I did not refresh the page to see the answer by Kenneth. This can be ignored.